# Load another page takes long time with jquery load

Tags: jquery

```
function link1() { 
    jQuery('#container').load('page2.html'); 
}
```

I am using simple function to load another page to index.html div. This works fine on local but when I push this to live its takes 30-40 seconds to load and if I click same link twice it loads again.

Is there any way to load page quickly?

Comment: The connection between your machine and the server might just be slow. Or `page2.html` is really really big.

Comment: Does it take as much as long if you access page2.html directly from your browser?

Comment: What's the size of the page you're trying to load?
Also, if you call the function twice, the link will load again, since jQuery doesn't cache the requests automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to load page quickly?

Nothing that you can do in this page  will help, maybe the server is just very busy or old.

But you can "disable" that link:

```
function link1() { 
    jQuery('#linkd').attr('href','#')
    jQuery('#container').load('page2.html'); 
}
```

You can return it's `href` when the load is finished if you like to.

Comment: It's glitchy, as in the main wrapper collapses to the left as the page loads, ten juts back to the right, but there's no significant slow down between any of the pages being loaded.

Comment: @MetalFrog. sorry I couldn't understand what you wrote.

Comment: @gdoron Not your code, the site he linked. It's super glitchy.

Comment: @user1185158 Your site makes a TON of requests. It's going to be slow.

Comment: yes.. I'm using xml to read data. Apparently all pages data comes from xml so I have to call it repeatedly. Can you suggest me better way. Thanks in advance!!